# How can I find the PhD thesis of A. V. Kostochka?

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

I've searched for the doctoral thesis of Alexandr V Kostochka in internet but couldn't find it. Can somebody help me?

I have searched in his [publications list](https://kostochk.web.illinois.edu/publ.html) (which contains only one article published before 1980) and the [library website](https://search.grainger.illinois.edu/discovery/splitsearch.asp?typeofsearch=keyword&searcharg=Kostochka+1978&OPERATE=GO&selection=gen) of the University of Illinois.
I have also asked Kostochka himself and another author who cited him for a copy of Kostochka's thesis. I have got no replies (which is understandable because they are busy).
The thesis is in Russian; I would like to get a copy of the thesis in some language.

Details:
Kostochka, Alexandr V. "Upper bounds of chromatic functions of graphs" (in Russian). Doct. Thesis. Novosibirsk, 1978.

Comment: Searching at https://www.ideals.illinois.edu/search?rpp=10&etal=0&scope=/&query=A+V+Kostochka&page=3&sort_by=0&order=DESC did not help either.

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful but this paper of Kostochka might cover some material of his thesis http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=dan&paperid=41118&option_lang=eng

Comment: The names of the paper and of the thesis are very close, and the paper is from 1977 (unfortunately, the paper seems to be only in Russian and without proofs)

Comment: @SashaKozachinskiy Thank you for your effort. A paper with very similar name is published in Journal of Combinatorial Theory, Series B in 1977 ([link to paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0095-8956(77)90037-5)). But, the content looks different to me.